# Firebase Custom Attribute Filter for Events

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have integrated Firebase in my app and captured some custom events. When I logged into Firebase console I can't find my custom attributes in filter option under **user properties** or **audience**. In **AWS Pinpoint** it's straightforward and we can filter it. But in Firebase is there any code we need to add or is there any method to add it?

Comment: Use "Edit parameter reporting" for your custom event to specify which parameter you'd like to see. 10 text and 40 number parameters are allowed to add. The rest is through BigQuery only

Comment: Hi Michael thanks for the reply. Yeah i tried that but the reports shows only no of events occured with **(not set)** Checkbox. How to see no of users interacted with. Lets say I have a cricket app with list of matches, users who clicks the match gets captured in firebase. 
Event is `Match_clicked - [match_name,datetime,user_id]` In console i can see **match_clicked** report but i need to see no users who clicked on specific match in that report like India vs Aus - 20users, Pak vs Ban - 10users etc. is it only possible if i use Bigquery? @MichaelSotnikov

Comment: you have to check if you report events properly and your param "match_name" is really set. I do see grouping with events/users number per each unique parameter value added as text parameter for reporting

Comment: Here is screenshot with example: https://imgur.com/TmRQ5QI

Comment: Ow ok that's what i needed, will check the code. Thanks a lot.